# TypeScript function signature in abstract class doesn't need to match interface

Tags: oop, typescript, interface, abstract-class

In the following example, interface IFoo declares a function signature requiring two number arguments.  Abstract class BaseFoo implements this interface, but declares the function with a different signature.  Finally, concrete class Foo extends BaseFoo and implements BaseFoo's version of the function declaration.

```
interface IFoo {
    func(x: number ): number
}

abstract class BaseFoo implements IFoo {
    abstract func(x: number): number
}

class Foo extends BaseFoo {
    func() { return -1 } // Does not match interface func declaration
}

let foo: IFoo = new Foo()  // Should not be able to instantiate a Foo as an IFoo
let y = foo.func()  // Should not be able to call without an argument
console.log(y)
```

This contrived example illustrates something that happened in real life: I had an existing interface in a codebase.  I updated one of it's function's signatures, with the expectation that the compiler would help me find all the classes who would need to be updated.  But, no errors.

Why am I allowed to instantiate an abstract class with a function signature that doesn't match the interface?

Comment: How does the signature differ between `IFoo` and `BaseFoo` ??  Re: *Abstract class BaseFoo implements this interface, but declares the function with a different signature.*

Comment: The TypeScript FAQ addresses this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Comment: "Should not be able to call without an argument" You can't? Well at least my tsc complains that you are passing an invalid number of arguments